# C# Sorting objects multiple keys

Tags: c#, sorting, object, key

I am developing an app for WP7.
I pull some data out of a Sterling Database and put in into my own objects.  These objects I am deriving a date attribute and setting that - it has a time already (that has been held on the object in the Sterling database).

I then want to sort these objects by date and time before presenting them.  Currently Date and time are separate String fields but I can combine them into a DateTime attribute if I want.

Is there a recommended way of doing this.  I have seen several options.. but not sure what is the best approach.

Any advice appreciated here.  - thanks

Comment: you can declare DateTime property in derived object which will have logic for combinig date and time from exist properties and then use sorting on it

Comment: thanks for this... what is the best way to sort it?

Comment: you can sort using LINQ OrderBy, also you get all benefits described in first answer by Jesus Ramos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you combine into a DateTime it makes your code a lot smaller. The reason for this is that DateTime supports comaprison operators such as <, >, ==, etc. That way you can just say (time1 < time2) or whatever your comparison function does.